# How to stop a build by buildnumber in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

We uses notes (comments) from Gitlab to issue a couple of user-commands, for example retry a build that seems to have failed from a failed integration etc. We would now like to ask jenkins to stop a build. We have got the buildnumber from the comment (through a callback to to gitlab searching the comments) so we know what build to stop but now we stumbled on the problem. We don't seem to find an api-call to stop the build by buildnumber alone.

We could of course make a request to https://server/project/buildnumber/stop (same url as used by the ui) but then we have to enable the crumbIssuer and according to Ops open for a CSRF-attack.

Is there a way to do this operation from inside a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to Manage Jenkins > Script Console.

Run the following script setting the job name and number of the hung build accordingly:

```
def build = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("jobName").getBuildByNumber(jobNumber)
build.doStop()
build.doKill()
```

Otherwise you can create a separate pipeline job and configure the above script

Abort the job build from a cid node (if the previous option did not help):

```
Log in to any cid node.

Run:

cd /srv/volumes/jenkins/jobs/<job-name>/builds/
rm -rf <hung-build-number>
```

Comment: Bummer: "Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature." Will try to hunt down an administrator with that kind of permissions.